# Can I manipulate the render order of UI Components

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout, uicomponent

Lets say I want to add a custom field to my checkout. I know I can do that by adding a UI Component to my custom `checkout_index_index.xml`, like explained in [the official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html) and covered in various questions on this site.

However, I am wondering if it's also possible to manipulate the order in which these components are rendered? The various layout XML files are merged into one and it seems that the order of how elements are added to `<item name="children" xsi:type="array"/>` is leading for the order of rendering.

Is there anyway how I can manipulate this (preferably by only using XML)?

Comment: just shooting in the dark here, but isn't there a `<item name="sort_order"` or something?

Comment: Thanks Marius for reminding me that somethings trial and error is indeed a very efficient way to discover new undocumented features in Magento. It turns out there is. I'll just go and answer my own question then.

Answer (score 2):

Like Marius points out sometimes you just need to do some trial and error to fix your problems. It turns out there is a configuration setting for your UI Component:

```
<item name="some_field" xsi:type="array">
    ...
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
    </item>
    ...
</item>
```